# Check if values are true in an array and return the indices of those value in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array Box

```
const box = [ true, false, true, false, true, false, false ];
```

I want to return the indices if the value is true

For example, in this, it should return [0,2,4].

I have written this code and it is giving error

```js
const box = [ true, false, true, false, true, false, false ];
const index = box.findIndex(x => x ==="true");
console.log(index);
```

Comment: That code returns -1

Comment: "it is giving error" - please provide the error or describe the problem more in detail

Comment: `x => x ==="true"` is wrong, its checking a string, it should be `x => x === true`  or just `x => x`. However it still will only return the first index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop will do the job:

```js
let indexes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  if (box[i]) indexes.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with either the index or an empty array.

```js
const
    box = [true, false, true, false, true, false, false],
    indices = box.flatMap((b, i) => b ? i : []);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 1):

That code returns `-1` because there is not a value equals to `"true"` as a string.

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to generate the desired output as follow:

*This is assuming every value is a boolean*

```js
const box = [ true, false, true, false, true, false, false ];
const result = box.reduce((r, bool, i) => r.concat(bool ? i : []), []);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: What about using spread syntax? `box.reduce((r, bool, i) => bool ? [...r,i] : r), []);` . just an alternative little improvement (IMO)

Comment: @JanStránský yeah, that's another approach.

Comment: I always prefer this way.