# Get all Indexes of Objects in Array - from Array in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

i´m struggling with a Array in a Object stored in a Array with Objects from which I want return all Indicies.

Function to generate Object looks like this:

```
const addArray = function(a, b) {
    const object = {
        name: a,
        rooms: b
    };
    testArray.push(object);
};
```

What I want to achieve is to cycle through the "testArray" and return every Index from the Object where the Array Rooms contains "Office" for example.

I´ve already tried to use a function like this but I don´t seem to be able to get the right Syntax for the Array in the Object:

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.rooms.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Additional Informations to Data:

A Object with data filled would look like this:

```
const device = {
        name: "TV",
        rooms: ["Living Room", "Bedroom"]
    };
```

After generating Objects like this I push them to an array witch only contains this objects (see `function addArray`)

Comment: please add the array, you are talking about and the wanted result of it.

Comment: it looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63768217/1447675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.flatMap()` to map each value of the array at matches `val` to it's index, and the rest to empty array, which will be removed by the flatMap:

```js
const getAllIndexes =(arr, val) => arr.flatMap((v, i) => v === val ? i : [])

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]

const result = getAllIndexes(arr, 1)

console.log(result)
```

Using your array of objects, you'll need to compare a value, or check if an object meets some condition. It's better in this case to replace `val` with a predicate function:

```js
const getAllIndexes =(arr, pred) => arr.flatMap((v, i) => pred(v) ? i : [])

const arr = [{ rooms: [1, 2, 3] }, { rooms: [2, 1, 1] }, { rooms: [3, 2, 2] }, { rooms: [1, 2, 1] }]

const result = getAllIndexes(arr, o => o.rooms.includes(1))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your answer! 
If I run the Code you provided it works just right but as soon as I replace your Array with my array i don´t get any Returned indices. 

For Clarification: 
The Array Contains the Object -> the Object contains a name and a Array -> I want to find indices in the last array. 

Is there any additional Info I could provide which would help?

Thank you!

Comment: @Midoxx, please add your data to the question.

Comment: An example of the input data, and the expected result.

Comment: I´ve added more Informations in Question - please let me know if you need further infos!

Comment: The expected result is a flat array of indexes?

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect! Have a great evening!

Comment: You're welcome :) and have a great evening as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Array.prototype.map and Array.prototype.filter

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    return arr.map(i=> {
        let room = i.rooms;
        return room.indexOf(val);
    }).filter(a=>{
        a != -1;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure `rooms` from the device and get the index, if the wanted value is found.

```
const
    room = 'Office',
    indices = array.flatMap(({ rooms }, i) => rooms.includes(room) ? i : []);
```

---

The above code features a former [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63768336/1447675) from me with hacking [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).